# запускаю свой первый тест на selenide.Selenium тесты запускаются без проблем.Зависимости в maven есть

Tags: java, selenide, intelij

запускаю свой первый тест на selenide.Selenium тесты запускаются без проблем.Зависимости в maven есть.

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;

public class SSelenideTest {
    @Test
    public void userCanSearchGoogle() {
        open("https://www.google.com/");
```

Ошибка в консоли

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.setHeadless(boolean)'

    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.ChromeDriverFactory.createChromeOptions(ChromeDriverFactory.java:37)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.ChromeDriverFactory.create(ChromeDriverFactory.java:26)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.lambda$createWebDriver$1(WebDriverFactory.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258)
```

Comment: Скорее всего несоответствие версий `Seleniude` и selenium. `setHeadless` в `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions` существует з версии ~3.6 selenium. Какие версии используются?

Comment: Спасибо Вам за отзыв. Версия selenide  <version>5.11.1</version>. а версия selenium <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>

Answer (score 1):

selenide 5.11.1 [использует](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/selenide/5.11.1) selenium 3.141.59.

4.x - это уже новая мажорная версия и там API изменилось несовместимым образом (в часности изменилась работа з options). Так что используйте версию селениума 3.141.59.

Версия selenide с поддержкой selenium 4 еще [не вышла](https://github.com/selenide/selenide/issues/1162) так как и селенум 4 еще не вышел, а есть только альфа версия.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое очееень выручили)))